# Data type that's a pair of functions?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, idris

I have a data type that's a pair of chainable functions. In Idris this is

```
data Foo i o = MkFoo (i -> ty) (ty -> o)
```

I hope it's fairly obvious what that means in Haskell. Is this a widely used construct, with a name perhaps?

Comment: What are you hoping to do with one of these that can't be done with an `i -> o`?

Comment: @DanielWagner: Check out the [`type-aligned`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-aligned) package, and the linked paper [Reflection Without Remorse](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/zseq.pdf) (PDF) which shows a nifty example of using this pattern for 1. typing an efficient code pattern as a data structure, and thus 2. allowing an efficient choice of *representation* for that structure, according to how it will be used.

Comment: @JonPurdy Those data structures seem considerably more involved than `Foo`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think you might have simplified my problem. I did try using `i -> o` a while ago, with no luck. Tried it a different way this time. So I guess this is now an academic question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you wanting `ty` to be an existential type?

```
type Foo :: Cat Type
data Foo i o where
 MkFoo :: (i -> ty) -> (ty -> o) -> Foo i o
                ^^      ^^
                |       |
             does not appear in the result type
```

---

In [`Data.Profunctor.Composition`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.6.2/docs/Data-Profunctor-Composition.html) there is

```
type Pro :: Type
type Pro = Type -> Type -> Type

type Procompose :: Pro -> Pro -> Pro
data Procompose pro2 pro1 іn out where
  Procompose :: pro2 xx out -> pro1 іn xx -> Procompose pro2 pro1 іn out
```

which `Foo` can be defined in terms of

```
type Foo :: Cat Type
type Foo = Procompose (->) (->)

                 we quantify `ty` here because it's existential
                                      |
                                      vvvvvvvvv
pattern MkFoo :: forall іn out. () => forall ty. (іn -> ty) -> (ty -> out) -> Foo іn out
pattern MkFoo one two = Procompose two one
```

There is also the concept of a free category is a type-aligned list; i.e. a list of chainable functions

```
type (~>) :: Cat (k -> Type)
type f ~> g = (forall x. f x -> g x)

type Quiver :: Type -> Type
type Quiver ob = ob -> ob -> Type

type Cat :: Type -> Type
type Cat ob = Quiver ob

infixr 5 :>>>

type FreeCategory :: Quiver ~> Cat
data FreeCategory cat a b where
 Id     :: FreeCategory cat a a
 (:>>>) :: cat a b -> FreeCategory cat b c -> FreeCategory cat a c
```

which can be written as a type-aligned list of length 2:

```
type Foo :: Cat Type
type Foo = FreeCategory (->)

                 we quantify `ty` here because it's existential
                                      |
                                      vvvvvvvvv
pattern MkFoo :: forall іn out. () => forall ty. (іn -> ty) -> (ty -> out) -> Foo іn out
pattern MkFoo one two = one :>>> two :>>> Id
```

---

Free categories can also be defined as `Free2 Category` by passing the `Category` class to `Free2`.. a bit of a rambly answer

```
type (~~>) :: Cat (k1 -> k2 -> Type)
type f ~~> g = (forall x. f x ~> g x)

type Free2 :: (Cat ob -> Constraint) -> Quiver ob -> Cat ob
type Free2 cls cat a b = (forall xx. cls xx => (cat ~~> xx) -> xx a b)

type FreeCategory :: Quiver ~> Cat
type FreeCategory cat a b = Free2 Category cat a b
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want `ty` to appear in the result type, no. I'm going to need to stare at this for a while cos I don't know much category theory

Comment: I probably drowned it out in the noise but you can define your own type or use `Procompose`, for your own type you have to add `.. = forall ty.` after the equality sign or use GADT syntax like I did but you can do it without involving category theory

Comment: You can always skip the standalone kind signature, ideone is using an ancient version of ghc (8.4.4) and it doesn't have it. Here is a version that imports `Data.Kind (Type)` and has the correct language pragmas. You can also unfold `Cat Type` = `Type -> Type -> Type`: https://ideone.com/vaaxoo

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe an alternative, anti-answer.

To elaborate on @DanielWagner's comment, if you define this type so that it is not parameterized in `ty`, as in @Iceland_jack's answer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Foo i o where
  Foo :: (i -> ty) -> (ty -> o) -> Foo i o
```

then I believe you will discover that literally the only interesting thing you can do with a value of this type is compose the two components to get the resulting composed function `i -> o`:

```
onlyWayToUseFoo :: Foo i o -> (i -> o)
onlyWayToUseFoo (Foo f g) = g . f
```

So, I think the answer is **no,** this is not a widely used construct in Haskell and it does not have a name, because it can't be used in any meaningful way that would make it different from just having a function `i -> o`.

In fact, `onlyWayToUseFoo` gives half the isomorphism between `Foo i o` and `i -> o`, and you can use this for the other half:

```
toFoo :: (i -> o) -> Foo i o
toFoo = Foo id
```

so I think `Foo i o` is just an unnecessarily complicated representation of the type `i -> o`.

I mean, I *could* be missing something, and I would certainly be grateful to anyone who could demonstrate my wrongness.

Comment: Actually, it occurs to me that maybe in the context of fine control of evaluation this might be useful.  You could conceivably use `Foo` to force evaluation of an application of an `i -> o` function, but only half-way?